# Where do I find the total invocations per month of all Cloud Functions in the GCP console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

According to [Cloud Functions Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing), the first 2 million invocations per month are free. Beyond 2 million, the price/million is $0.40.

**Now, is there an easy way to show the (running) total invocations per month of all Cloud Functions of a project in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)?**

Since they are billed per million per month, there must be such a functionality. The only thing I found so far is the [Metrics Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer), which, however, does not seems to provide a running total functionality.

Am I missing something?

*PS: In Firebase, there is a Functions Usage tab which shows the total invocations per day and the overall total within a given period. Since Firebase is based on GCP, this should also be possible to show somewhere in the GCP console, or not?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [Billing Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing) and follow it through to your billing account, you can select just the Cloud Functions service, at which point it will show you the various billing aspects of Cloud Functions - including the total number of invocations for the selected time period. You can then save the view and get back to it easily later.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to find it